# How does one fetch a web page in Julia?

Tags: http, url, request, fetch, julia

I am developing an application that fetches & parses web pages in Julia. I wish to learn how to fetch a url, and also how to fetch a url from beyond an authenticating proxy in Julia.

Comment: This question feels like you're asking for a tutorial, which is not really appropriate for StackOverflow. I suspect this is why it has been down-voted. As it stands you don't really appear to have encountered any specific problem.

Comment: Maybe `download` or `https://github.com/JuliaWeb/LibCURL.jl`.

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach could be like this. This is accessing Reddit's cat forum "aww" using the JSON and Requests packages:

```
using JSON, Requests

subreddit  = "aww"
first_request = get("http://www.reddit.com/r/$(subreddit)/new/.json")
request_json = JSON.parse(first_request.data)

for children in request_json["data"]["children"]
    for child in children["data"]
        if first(child) == "title" println(last(child)) end
    end
end
```

with predictable results:

```
Zeus this is reddit, reddit meet Zeus
My blue eyed baby all grown up :)
She had a long walk (:
Charley isn't too picky with where he sleeps
My puppy accidentally did a role-poly
Meet Oliver, Oliver Wood.
Happy World Turtle Day!
Check out my new adorable boxer pup!
My handsome guard cat was being all picturesque this morning
Fluffy cow!
Our Husky/St Bernard mix named Gracie.
Tuxedo Derp!
She just wanted to snuggle and go to sleep. He wasn't having it.
Milo Greetings
This cat has prettier eyes than any human.
20+ Asshole Cats Being Shamed
Too bad this isn't a trick and it's actually stuck to his nose.
Blue family!
Just a puppy eating ice cream
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful replies. I am afraid I submitted my question without completing it fully. I am behind a proxy that does not allow me to fetch any packages from github using the julia commandline. So my question really is: How do I copy the files of the Requests package from github & create the appropriate folder structure to use it? I searched the net but could not find any good answer to this problem.